# System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001 in apex trigger

Tags: trigger

I have a simple trigger on account object. In which i am querying the account records. When I am trying to insert 5000 account records in bulk the

> System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

is being thrown at line 3 i.e `List<Account> accountList = [select id,BillingState from account];` can anyone help me with the solution?

```apex
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        List<Account> accountList = [select id,BillingState from account];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to accomplish.  You cannot query all of the Accounts in your system every time an Account is updated.  It is not properly bulkified https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk

Answer (score 3):

Since the exact use case is not known, the more appropriate solution will be to include a where clause such that it brings the required records which shall not be greater than 50000. At present, it will bring all the records in the list from the object which may be more than 50K.

Comment: currently do not have any account records in my org. I am just trying to insert 5000 records in bulk and also I cannot use the ''WHERE" clause as I need to fetch all the account records. I know we can handle such logic in Batch is there any way that we can do in the apex trigger?

Comment: put a limit at the end of the query to 49800. The remaining 200 records shall be part of Trigger.new assuming batch size of insert is 200.

Answer (score 3):

That query is retrieving *every* Account record in your org. I do not know what your ultimate aim is here - perhaps you are learning and just trying different things - but you need a `WHERE` clause to retrieve a specific subset of records.  Something like

```
...WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New
```

Again, the specifics of the `WHERE` clause are dependent on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I currently do not have any account records in my org. I am just trying to insert 5000 records in bulk and also I cannot use the ''WHERE" clause as I need to fetch all the account records. I know we can handle such logic in Batch is there any way that we can do in the apex trigger?